# Load images after reopening the mobile app - Flutter

Tags: image, flutter

I am trying to display the picked images from gallery in a grid view . I have stored the images path in a list and displaying in the Gridview. After exiting the app and restarting , the grid view is empty. I want to retain the picked images for the next time when the user opens the app again, user should be able to see the gridview with previously picked images.

I am using imagepicker package in flutter. Since the image is stored in a cache , next time when the user restarts again , cache is cleared and the images list is empty. I have no idea about, how to display even after reopens the app?

Comment: in `initState`, get the images path from database.

Comment: M not using any database here

Comment: you need to use for this.

Comment: Is any other option available without db?

Comment: or sharedPreferences.

Comment: Reading about it . Will update shortly if I'm able to crack this